# Windows authentication with Nodejs and IIS; issue getting username

Tags: node.js, iis, http-headers, single-sign-on, iisnode

I'm trying to setup a NodeJS web app with IIS to **first** use Windows Authentication, if not found **then** have the ability to use Anonymous Authentication to access the website.

Following this article https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/87, I promoted "*the IIS server variables to X-iisnode-* HTTP request headers*" as you can see in the config file below.

The problem is this: when Anonymous Authentication is off in IIS, all domain users get authenticated correctly, but Anonymous users can't access the website at all.
When I turn on Anonymous Authentication, **all** users access anonymously and the variable auth_user always comes back empty.

Is there a way to tell IIS, enforce Windows Authentication first, if not a domain user then use Anonymous Authentication?

I'm running the NodeJS app in a Windows 2012 server, iisnode, IIS 8

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="app">
          <match url="^/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
            <rewriteMaps>
                <rewriteMap name="http://website/">
                    <add key="http://website/" value="192.168.10.1/" />
                </rewriteMap>
            </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>

    <iisnode promoteServerVars="AUTH_USER,AUTH_TYPE" />

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also tried using node-sspi to get the user's information, which worked when I ran the application on stand-alone mode, it failed when I tried to run it behind IIS... has anybody tried this?

Comment: in my opinion, there is no way that let iis enforce windows authentication first then use anonymous authentication. you need to write your own code.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal any suggestion as to how to do so?